# I want to optimize the SQL query because it took too much time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an issue with this SQL query. I want to get number of 'oprs' created by each roles.

For example :

```
| Projects | oprs count (role A) |    oprs count (role B)      |
|----------|---------------------|-----------------------------|
| Project1 |     100             |             10              |
| Project2 |     10              |             20              |
| Project3 |     80              |             30              |
```

[image]

I have done this query but it's very slow because table of 'oprs' is huge, Could you please help to make it better ?

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT
    pr.id 'project ID',
    pr.name 'project',
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT o.id)
        FROM
            oprs o
                LEFT JOIN
            accounts ac ON ac.id = o.create_account_id AND NOT(ac.is_deleted)
                LEFT JOIN
            users u ON u.account_id = ac.id AND NOT(u.is_deleted)
                LEFT JOIN
            links_users_roles lur ON lur.user_id = u.id AND NOT(lur.is_deleted)
                LEFT JOIN
            roles r ON r.id = lur.role_id
        WHERE
            o.project_id = pr.id
            AND r.id = 31
    )AS 'count oprs created with role A',
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT o.id)
        FROM
            oprs o
                LEFT JOIN
            accounts ac ON ac.id = o.create_account_id AND NOT(ac.is_deleted)
                LEFT JOIN
            users u ON u.account_id = ac.id AND NOT(u.is_deleted)
                LEFT JOIN
            links_users_roles lur ON lur.user_id = u.id AND NOT(lur.is_deleted)
                LEFT JOIN
            roles r ON r.id = lur.role_id
        WHERE
            o.project_id = pr.id
            AND r.id = 252
    )AS 'count oprs created with role B'
FROM
    projets pr
GROUP BY pr.id
```

And this is the explain of query :

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing the query as a single aggregation query.  I don't know if this will be faster -- but it may.  And it is definitely simpler:

```
SELECT pr.id, pr.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lur.role_id = 31 THEN o.id END),
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lur.role_id = 252 THEN o.id END)
FROM projects pr LEFT JOIN
     oprs o
     ON o.project_id = pr.id LEFT JOIN
     accounts ac
     ON ac.id = o.create_account_id AND
        NOT(ac.is_deleted) LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.account_id = ac.id AND
        NOT(u.is_deleted) LEFT JOIN
     links_users_roles lur
     ON lur.user_id = u.id AND
         NOT(lur.is_deleted)
GROUP BY pr.id, pr.name;
```

Notice that one table is "missing".  It is not needed because the role id is in `links_users_roles`.

Next, I would question whether `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is needed.  It adds overhead.  I wouldn't be surprised if it is not really necessary.  That would also speed up the query.

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon Linoff explained, you can refactor your code to make it simpler to read. I would like to add that you have several ways to improve this. First, you could implement a cron job that periodically loads this query and saves the result, so when the data is needed only the result would be queried instead of computing the long process again and again. Next, you may want to index a few fields, like foreign keys, such as `project_id`, which will increase the performance of your query. It will slightly decrease the performance of saving records though.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up where Gordon left off...

- The `LEFTs` are probably unnecessary.
- If `NOT(is_deleted)` can be turned into either `is_deleted = 0` or `is_deleted IS NULL`, then we can discuss improving some of the indexes.
- For many-to-many tables, the indexes can probably be improved; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
- If you want to discuss it further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`